# Metric tensor $g_{ij}$ for function equality $f(x) = 0$

Tags: differential-geometry

From a constructive perspective, I have trouble obtaining the metric. The explicit statement is below.

Let a $n$-dimensional vector space X endowed with metric $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle^X$ and basis $B_X$, and a $(n-m)$-dimensional submanifold $\mathcal{F}$ given by level sets $f = 0$, homeomorphic to either an hyperplane, hypersphere or n-torus.

I know I may parameterize the level set by the tuple $F(x) = (x, f(x))$ and due a pullback $F^*\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$, but my nescience get me stuck.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "a $m$-dimensional function equality $f$ [...] such that $f(x)=0$ holds"?

Comment: Take for example a sphere defined on euclidean (vector) space: Its definition is given by equality $\lVert x \rVert - r = 0$, for some $r > 0$.

Comment: Ok. This is non-standard terminology I guess: I would have used "a submanifold defined by the equation $f(x)=0$"

Comment: Great, may we build some mathematics from them?

Comment: We may. How did you guess this form of the metric? Is $f$ a submersion?

Comment: I think OP actually means the graph of the function $f$. Otherwise the components (and dimensionality) don't make sense.

Comment: I made assumptions about Euclidian space and fixed the dimension of the resulting graph surface. I thank you @peek-a-boo, I find the hidden mistake. ;)

Comment: @peek-a-boo That is indeed what I was thinking about when seeing the form of $g_{ij}$ OP provided. And now I am confused

Comment: The expression $\langle (e_i,f_{x_i}),(e_j,f_{x_j})\rangle^X$ doesn't make sense since the entries are not vectors of $X$

Comment: I agree sorrowly . :'(

Comment: Anyway, I think [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4421502/788724) is what you are looking for

Comment: My knowledge in surfaces only allow me to talk in terms of Euclidean space. May you translate it in terms of undergraduate concepts? Preferably, in terms of this book: https://books.google.com.br/books/about/Differential_Geometry_of_Curves_and_Surf.html?id=6BAZAQAAIAAJ&redir_esc=y

Comment: Then $\partial_i = e_i$, $f_i = f_{x_i}$, and "pullback", "$F^*\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$" are just graduate terminology that basically means "the induced metric on the graph of $f$". The rest should be understandable

Comment: Daunting but comprehensible. How does provided answer agree with the dimensionality you made me aware of?

Comment: So $\mathcal F\subset X$ *is* or *is not* the $(n-m)$-dimensional level set $f=0$ for $f\colon X\to\Bbb R^m$?  Can someone clarify and edit to make the question explicit and clear? OP is referencing baby DoCarmo, in which we work with surfaces only parametrically. A lot of implicit differentiation is going to have to take place here.

Comment: Yes, it is a submergifold (self-cooked word submerged+submanifold). Baby doCarmo for baby steps.

Comment: Your final sentence is now completely no good. Try some simple examples. A level set is *not* (in an obvious way) a graph. This is why I continue to complain.

Comment: Does homeomorphism to smooth known smooth suffice?